# Count dependents in other sheets VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I want to count the number of dependents of a cell in same sheet as well as in other sheets using VBA.

I have used below code and results are in the picture.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbef9.png)

```
Sub tst()
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In selection
cell.offset(0, -1).value = cell.Dependents.Count
Next cell
End Sub
```

There are two problems

1. In the cell C6 is using B6 for two times but VBA is counting only 1 dependent cell at this address rather than number of time B6 is used.
2. Cell B6 and other cells are also used in **Sheet2** but VBA is not counting at all.

Comment: Seems to work as documented: .Dependents counts the dependent cells, not the number of times they are used, and the documentation explicitly states: "The Dependents property only works on the active sheet and cannot trace remote references."

Comment: Yup as @Paul said, the property you are trying to use isn't going to work for you.  For Excel, this is more useful in optimising recalculations using a dependency tree. What are you trying to calculate here? I mean what is the true meaning of counting all references in all formulae in the whole sheet?

Comment: Which incidentally is what you would need to do in order to get an accurate figure. Loop through all cells in the sheet. Use regex on each formula and count the number of occurrences of references. If you are using named ranges, things could get tricky.

Comment: I have a long list of amounts in sheet1 and I am linking them in calculations on sheet1/sheet2/sheet3 but at a point in time I want to make sure if I have linked all items from sheet1 to sheet1/sheet2/sheet3 and also be sure that nothing is linked twice. so i want to count the dependents infront of every amount in sheet1.